# How are bits arranged in a reduced-range variable in Ada?

Tags: range, ada, bit

Let's say I've created a type in Ada:

```
type Coord_Type is range -32 .. 31;
```

What can I expect the bits to look like in memory, or specifically when transmitting this value to another system?

I can think of two options.

One is that the full (default integer?) space is used for all variables of "Coord_Type", but only the values within the range are possible. If I assume 2s complement, then, the value 25 and -25 would be possible, but not 50 or -50:

```
0000 0000 0001 1001 ( 25)
1111 1111 1110 0111 (-25)
0000 0010 0011 0010 ( 50) X Not allowed
1111 1111 1100 1110 (-50) X Not allowed
```

---

The other option is that the space is compressed to only what is needed. (I chose a byte, but maybe even only 6 bits?) So with the above values, the bits might be arranged as such:

```
0000 0000 0001 1001 ( 25)
0000 0000 1110 0111 (-25)
0000 0000 0011 0010 ( 50) X Not allowed
0000 0000 1100 1110 (-50) X Not allowed
```

Essentially, does Ada further influence the storage of values beyond limiting what range is allowed in a variable space? Is this question, Endianness, and 2s complement even controlled by Ada?

Comment: If you simply do the above, you leave it up to the compiler. If 32-bit integers are fastest, that may be what you get (and out-of-range values will raise an exception pointing spookily close to the error...) If you need to control the representation, look at "pragma Pack", "attribute Size" or Ada-2012 Aspect clauses and so on. You can specify an array of these packed on 6-bit boundaries if you must. Compilers will either obey or report that extreme packing is unsupported. Hopefully someone will give a detailed answer. Meantime you can search the Ada RM for these and get started...

Comment: Right, Ada doesn't specify how numbers are represented, although it provides some aspects, attributes, and pragmas to help you control this, and individual compilers may provide others.  Ada doesn't require that numbers be stored in 2s complement, although you'd be hard-pressed to find a computer that didn't, these days.  I did once work on some Burroughs mainframes that only worked with decimal numbers--no binary arithmetic instructions.  (They were geared toward COBOL.)  I doubt Ada was ever implemented on any of those beasts.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know: that "pragma Pack" and the compiler were the areas to be searching for answers for bit allocation. Thank you.

Comment: Defining 'Size and 'Alignment aspects/properties have an effect on it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the type like that, you leave it up to the compiler to choose the optimal layout for each architecture.  You might even get binary-coded-decimal (BCD) instead of two's complement on some architectures.